# Cubic Polynomial fitting with defined ranges for coefficients

Tags: linear-programming, regression, cubics

Is there a way, given a set of values $(x,y)$, to find a cubic polynomial $f(x)$ that fits the values?

My cubic polynomial is defined as

$c_0  +  c_1x +\frac {1}{2} c_2 x^2 +\frac {1}{6}c_3 x^3$

One condition being each co-efficient in above equation can only take values in between certain range (min, max) predefined for each coefficient.

I have tried with Least squares error algorithm to fit the points to the polynomial but I am not sure how to include the conditions for allowed range for coefficients in the algorithm.

What approach should I follow and which algorithms allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$, you want to minimize $$SSQ=\sum_{i=1}^n\left( c_0+c_1x_i+\frac 12 c_2x_i^2+\frac 13 c_3x_i^3-y_i\right)^2$$ subject to constraints $a_i\leq c_i\leq b_i$.

This is clearly an optimization problem with only bound constraints. Have a look [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-tool-with-the-fmincon-solver.html) for doing it using Matlab.

**Edit**

By the way, if you have access to a simple optimizer (unable to handle constraints), you could write $$c_i=a_i+\frac{b_i-a_i}{1+e^{-d_i}}$$ and use the $d_i$ as new unbounded variables. This switch the problem to a nonlinear regression.

Last : if you have access to a Fortran compiler, I could provide you a very simple and efficient subroutine solving the problem. Feel free to contact me (my e-mail address is in my profile).

Comment: Sorry I am refreshing my math skills after long break. What do you meant by simple optimizer and How can I understand the background behind how you derived the ci and converted the problem to non-linear regression ? I have sent a mail

Comment: Replace the $c_i$'s by their "new" definition. Then the problem is to find the $d_i$'s and the model is highly nonlinear with respect to parameters.

Comment: I have to calculate this in realtime as the new data comes in C Language,  is the fmincon if implemented in C the right solution ?